# Can I read what CCFLAGS were used for building a binary?

Tags: gcc, elf

Is there any way to read from compiled code what CCFLAGS (particularly the optimizations) were set at compile time?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387040/how-to-retrieve-the-gcc-version-used-to-compile-a-given-elf-executable but given it's on a different SE site I can't report it through the "flag" button.

Comment: @Shadok almost what he wants: your link refers to reading the GCC version, the asker wants to know if he can find the CFLAGS used for building the binary.

Comment: Sorry I think I swapped two links, here the one I wanted to link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189350/detect-gcc-compile-time-flags-of-a-binary

Comment: Thanks Shadok - if you add this as an answer I'll accept it. In my case the code was compiled with gcc 4.5 :) but the binary in question has been stripped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is but only with gcc >= 4.3,the switch `-frecord-gcc-switches` causes the whole command line to be put into ASCII commentaries.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189524/467966) for an answer to this question on SO.